# why does my pixel 3 still have the old gmail app?

Tags: gmail, google-pixel

Recently I got a pixel 3. A very nice phone and it is nice to know you are always among the firsts to receive a new version of android and the google apps. So I am confused why the gmail app still looks like the old gmail, where gmail on my one plus has the new interface.

Comment: What is the version of  the  gmail app?

Comment: 8.12.30.230564275. Release

Comment: Is this a brand new phone? Have you opened/logged in on the Play Store to allow updates on existing apps? Or, to make it to the point: did you mean there's no update for Gmail on Play Store?

Comment: @AndrewT. This literally happened to me 2 days ago. Brand new 3, old gmail. Play Store did not find an update for it. I manually re-installed it from apkmirror. Must have something to do with the way Google updates apps.

Comment: Just like @SiXandSeven8ths says, the phone is brand new, andoid is new, but gmail is old.

Comment: Oh joy, this morning Google decided to make the update available for my phone!